# 配列の要素が適切に削除できない

Tags: python

文字列の特定文字の配列番号を取得しようとしています。

リストの中の特定文字をfind関数で検索し、合致しない場合、-1が返り、その-1を削除しようとしておりますが、配列が [-1, -1, 8, -1, -1]から[8,-1]となり、最終の-1が残ってしまう現象がおきています。なぜ、最後の-1が残るのか、また対処方法のご指導を頂けませんでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
wage_sentence = "日給 1万545円 "

list_wage = []
list_wage.append(wage_sentence.find("以上"))
list_wage.append(wage_sentence.find("～"))
list_wage.append(wage_sentence.find("円"))
list_wage.append(wage_sentence.find("＋"))
list_wage.append(wage_sentence.find("+"))


for i in list_wage:
    if -1 in list_wage:
        list_wage.remove(-1)
   　　
end = min(list_wage)
```

Comment: 理由については[8.3. for 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)の「注釈」を参照して下さい。「注釈」に書かれていますが、この方法でリストの中身を削除するとすれば、`for i in list_wage:` を `for i in list_wage[:]:` に変更します。

Comment: 最終的な結果(インデックスのリスト)だけ必要であれば `list_wage = [wage_sentence.index(word) for word in ("以上", "～", "円", "＋", "+") if word in wage_sentence]` としても良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

処理ループを`for i in list_wage:`としたことが原因です。
例えば以下のようにすると、`-1`,`8`,`-1`の3回しかループしていないのが分かるでしょう。

```
for i in list_wage:
    print(i)
    if -1 in list_wage:
        list_wage.remove(-1)
```

このループでやるのなら、`for`を以下のようにします。
(@metropolisさんコメントの方法でも良いでしょう)

```
for i in range(len(list_wage)):
```

if文に相当する概念的に言えば、ループは以下の処理になるのでは？

```
while -1 in list_wage:
    list_wage.remove(-1)
```

リスト内包表記にすれば、ループ処理全体を1行で表すことも出来ます。

```
list_wage = [x for x in list_wage if x != -1]
```

参考：
[Pythonでリスト（配列）の要素を削除するclear, pop, remove, del](https://note.nkmk.me/python-list-clear-pop-remove-del/)

Comment: 勉強になりました、ありがとうございました。